# Splitting string causing Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'components'

Tags: swift

I have a function using webview IOS with swift 4. I am trying to explode `result`, but I am getting `Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'components'` and I have no idea how to fix this. I am new to swift.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('user_id').innerText") { (result, error) in
        if result != nil {
            let items = result.components(separatedBy: "|")
            self.ref?.child("people").child(result as! String).setValue(["device_token": self.deviceTokenStringfinal])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `result` can be anything: a string, a number, an array, a JSON object... depending on what your Javascript returns. Swift has no way of knowing that at compile time so it marks `result` as `Any`.

You must do a cast at runtime:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('user_id').innerText") { (result, error) in
        guard let result = result as? String else { return }

        let items = result.components(separatedBy: "|")
        self.ref?.child("people").child(result).setValue(["device_token": self.deviceTokenStringfinal])
    }
}
```